# Conditions under which a variety to remains smooth after base change (if p > 0)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, field-theory, projective-schemes

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field of positive characteristic and let $V$ be a smooth projective (irreducible) variety over $k$. Suppose that $K/k$ is a field extension such that $V_K:=V\times_{\text{Spec }k}\text{Spec }K$ remains reduced and irreducible.
Can we deduce from this that $V_K$ is smooth over $K$?

If not (and probably this is the case), what minimal assumptions are required to make sure that $V_K$ is smooth? Would it help if we knew that
$\text{tr. deg. }K/k=1$ and $k$ is algebraically closed in $K$?

Comment: "If not (and probably this is the case)..." Why the pessimism, dear Tomasz? I have good news for you :-)

Comment: Dear Tomasz, In light of Georges answer below, when you wrote "smooth ... over $k$", did you mean smooth in the technical sense (i.e. satisfying the non-vanishing of an appropriate Jacobian), or did you mean *regular*, i.e. the local rings are regular local rings (which agrees with smoothness over a perfect field, but not over non-perfect fields).  Regards,

Comment: Dear Matt, I am aware of this difference. So when I write "smooth" I mean "geometrically regular". Is this correct? In fact, I was planning to ask another question about the behavior of the "regularity" under the base change.

Comment: Dear Tomasz, Okay.  Note that one interpretation of the adjective *geometrically* in *geometrically regular* is  that the property in question is presumed to hold after all extensions of scalars.  But perhaps you saw an alternate definition in which it means just that the condition holds after passing to the algebraic closure of the original field? Then it is a theorem to show that regularity holds for all possible scalar extensions.  Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your question**
Given a variety  $V$ over a field $k$ and an extension field $k\to K$, the variety  $V$ is smooth over $k$ if and only of the variety $V_K$ is smooth over $K$.

**Vastly more general result**
Smoothness is compatible with base change in all generality: if an arbitrary morphism of schemes $X\to S$ is smooth, it will remain smooth after an arbitrary  base change $S'\to S$, i.e. $X\times _S S'\to S'$ will be  smooth too: EGA IV,4, Proposition (17.3.3) (iii).
And if $S'\to S$ is faithfully flat, then  descent of smoothness holds, namely if $X\times _S S'\to S'$ is smooth, then so was $X\to S$:  EGA IV,4, Corollaire (17.7.3) (ii).

**Edit**
Matt in his comment to the question nailed it: smoothness means that the determinant of some matrix is non zero and this does not depend on the field in which you  want to consider that the entries of the matrix belong.
 So despite the apparent inpenetrability of the EGA IV reference, this is essentially undergraduate stuff :-)

Comment: These are certainly good news :) However, I will need to ask another question about the behavior of regularity under the base change.

Comment: Dear Tomasz: yes, regularity can be destroyed by base change. And you are very welcome to ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you :) If you have a minute, please take a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607640/normal-curve-after-base-change-p-0).